# Using SQL Server sequence for calculate i.e. invoice number

Tags: sql-server, sequence

I have to calculate separate number for invoice per customer and per year. Is it possible to do this with a SQL Server sequence and `Next value for` ?

Comment: What does `"ms sql sequence and Next value for"` mean? Can you share some sample data and your desired results? I feel like a `GROUP BY` `ROLLUP` or some window functions would do the trick here, but without sample data and desired results, it's tough to guess.

Comment: When it's ok for you that an invoice number is just the next value of a sequence and gaps in numbering are allowed than you can use a sequence. When you needs a consecutive series for every customer and every year you can't use sequences

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that you need a window function, most likely `RANK()`

say you have you orders table

`order_id | cust_id | transaction_time |`

```sql
select
    CONCAT(Year(transaction_date), '-', rank() over (partition by cust_id, year(transaction_date) order by transaction_date desc, id)) as invoice_number
,   order_id
,   cust_id
,   transaction_time
from orders
```

to ensure that you don't have a duplicate invoice number per customer you must ensure that the order by breaks any ties.